# Snipping/cropping tool for Windows that lets you use a square/custom aspect ratio?

Tags: windows, images, image-processing

I need to crop hundreds of images and make them all squares. So sizes like 600x600, 650x650, 747x747, whatever.

Currently I'm going into MS Paint for each of them, manually cropping and resizing, and then saving.

This is very slow.

Is there a more efficient way such that I can maintain my sanity?

Ideally there would be some sort of snipping tool that lets me specify the aspect ratio, or allow for holding shift to make a square aspect ratio.

Comment: Are you scaling the image (resizing) or are you cropping (cutting edges/borders off to reduce image dimensions).  If you are cropping, how are you determining how much/where, or can it be done programmatically?

Comment: Manually, like with a snipping tool.

Comment: Like a snipping tool that has a fixed box of a certain dimension so that every snip is that dimension.  I believe I saw you in a couple other posts looking for the same thing that I am. I take snips of Google maps to past in and excel sheet. Then I have to crop and resize. I don’t have to do as much as you, so good luck.